# Is a double Rails install possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

I started to learn Ruby on Rails while ago so now I am going back and starting again. I have found that I do not have rails installed but I do have jewellery box and ruby installed. Will installing the rails installer again effect these or just add rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to read about [bundler](http://bundler.io/). You may have any versions of any gems at the same time using bundler and rails currently (from v 3.0) build on top of bundler.

Answer (score 1):

It will just add rails. You can also have separate gemsets that all contain their own rails installs that can have their own versions and stuff. Short answer though is that it will just add rails.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on rails version in your Gemfile (or when installing via *gem install*). If version isn't specified then it will be updated to latest after each *bundle install*.

In addition to specifying the rails version, I would recommend to use RVM (http://rvm.io/) for delimiting different gemsets for different applications.